# Convert [] to List With Constructor

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a class `PlaceInfo` that contains a private field of type `Result`. in the constructor of `PlaceInfo` i take parameter of type `Result`.

Now my `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchFind>(JsonData);` statement provides me `Result[]` in `res.Results`.

I have to construct a `List<PlaceInfo>`.

The simplest and thumb logical way is given below (that i am using currently).

```
foreach (var serverPlace in res.Results)
    lstPlaces.Add(new PlaceInfo(serverPlace));
```

Can anyone suggest me advanced constructs?

Comment: why you don't like `foreach`? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
lstPlaces = res.Results.Select(x => new PlaceInfo(x)).ToList();
```

remember to add `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Linq Select and ToList method

```
Result[] results = ...
List<PlaceInfo> places = results.Select(x => new PlaceInfo(x)).ToList();
```

The `Select` method is a projection, applying the given function to all the elements in your array. The `ToList` method takes the resultant `IEnumerable` and creates a `List`.